# Delphi XE8 Datanap : detect Ungraceful Disconnect with TDSHTTPWebDispatcher

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, datasnap

I develop a server Datasnap application based on a TDSHTTPWebDispatcher, witch implement the HTTP tunnel.

I'd like to detect graceless disconnections. Several sources indicates the use of the keepAliveEnablement property of a TDSTCPServerTransport.
This property doesn't exists with the TDSHTTPWebDispatcher.
I've tried to send callback to each connection to detect the presence, but the server crashes when it send a message to a disconnected session.

Any idea ?
Thank you